# How does Deus Ex: Human Revolution tie in to Deus Ex?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution, deus-ex

At the end of Deus Ex: Human Revolution and after the credits there is a goodie with some dialog that ties Human Revolution to the original Deus Ex, which is then followed by the Human Revolution title accompanied by the original Deus Ex title music.

Is this simply an easter egg for those of us that have played the original Deus Ex or is there a more direct follow-up planned to tie Human Revolution more directly to the orginal game?

Comment: The game just came out; isn't it a little early to be speculating about future tie-ins?

Comment: Isn't HR supposed to be the prequel to Deus Ex? I haven't played it yet, but I think it'd be more surprising if there wasn't a tie-in. :)

Comment: Deus Ex “Missing Link” DLC coming in October

Comment: I suppose it is early to speculate on future installments that fill the gap between DX:HR and DX. The amount of time that passes between the two would allow for a lot of content (DLC & sequel-prequels) to be released to fill in the grey areas. I guess I was just caught up in the DX fever that recurred after finishing DX:HR that I immediately wanted more. I'll just have to tide myself with replaying the original again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Missing Link" DLC has been announced (for October), but this will apparently be set in the time between Jenson leaving Hengsha and arriving in Singapore so will not carry the story forward past the end of the game, but it may well provide more exposition on how the games are linked.

However, they have already made some fairly strong links between DE:HR and the original. Specifically, the little hidden element from the credits (that you mention) infers that Megan Reed is working with the Bob Page (and therefore the Illuminati), so is presumably using Adam's DNA to help them develop the nano-augmentations that appear in Deus Ex and the "nanite-virus chimera" mentioned may presumably result in the Grey Death.

There are also other weaker links throughout the game, for example when Jenson detonates the bomb in Hengsha shipyard he inadvertently allows Tracer Tong (a major character in Deus Ex) to escape the island. There are others too, I'm sure, but I won't try to list them all here.

---

A few of the Wikia pages provide more in-depth information, here's a few that are the most pertinent:

[Deus Ex: Human Revolution, Plot](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Deus_Ex:_Human_Revolution#Plot)
[Adam Jenson, 2027](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Adam_Jensen#2027)
[JC Denton, Early Life](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/JC_Denton#Early_life)
[Nano-augmentation, The beginnings](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Nano-augmentation#The_beginnings)

Comment: Accepted, for the links to information that helps fill the voids between the two games. Hopefully though this question will eventually answer itself if/when more content is released.

Answer (score 1):

No sequel to Deus Ex: Human Revolution has been announced. However, since it has done well so far I wouldn't be surprised if Eidos Montreal was starting work on one soon.

I took the bit after the credits to just be a quick little tie in to the original Deus Ex. It also fits in well with the intro movie.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really tie in that much.

DX1 has something called killswitches which, naturally kill their augmented subjects when switched on. This is what megan is making.

The illuminati are mentioned, but it's not really explored. Same with FEMA.

Bob Page, the antagonist in DX1, is introduced briefly at the beginning and the end. Manderly's name is mentioned...

Basically the two games have little to do with eachother. The developers just made sure to mention just enough from the original to justify using "Deus Ex" in Human Revolution

Answer (score 0):

Actually its a prequel, with just enough room left over to expand a little on how the two fit in (obviously via DLC for this game, if they bother at all).

JC doesn't know his brother yet. That's because they are both adoptees to different couples supposedly. The old woman in DEx3 confirms this. He was actually known as JC Denton to her (from White Labs) prior to the fire that took his parents, (who weren't actually his parents but scientists). I could be wrong but I thought 'White Labs' was one of the many researchers into the genomic project initiative. Genomic projects (beginning as early as the 1960's) were everything from finding genetic to synthetic bonds all the way up to super soldiers and so on. It;s not a sinister thing, just science doing what's requested of it.

In DEx1, the two brothers discuss this and JC finds out more as he goes along in that game (if I remember correctly) so it's only loosely connected to anyone that didn't play the first game (or simply doesn't remember it).

Actually in playing this game, it dredged up a lot of the things I remember about the Original in order for me to be writing this. So I'd definitely say that its done its job well, to do that.

I wasn't surprised by Megan; much throughout the game pretty much softens the blow about what eventually occurs. It's completely irritating that you can't tell JC that he's barking up the wrong tree regarding her. If one could I would've tasked him to assassinate her as a priority target and then probe deeper into what's behind her. Alas we're **years** away from that kinda interactive entertainment.